# How do I write an image in xls with a custom size using Java and Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

How do I write an image with a custom size in xls using Java and Apache POI?
This is my code. It shows the given image with the default size but I need to customize the size.

```
Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("My Sample Excel");
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("images/myLogo.png");
byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
int pictureIdx = wb.addPicture(bytes, Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG);
inputStream.close();
CreationHelper helper = wb.getCreationHelper();
Drawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
ClientAnchor anchor = helper.createClientAnchor();
anchor.setCol1(1);
anchor.setRow1(2);
Picture pict = drawing.createPicture(anchor, pictureIdx);
pict.resize();
FileOutputStream fileOut = null;
fileOut = new FileOutputStream("data/myFile.xlsx");
wb.write(fileOut);
fileOut.close();
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try running these before calling `drawing.createPicture`:

```
anchor.setAnchorType(ClientAnchor.MOVE_AND_RESIZE);
anchor.setCol2(X);
anchor.setRow2(Y);
```

Comment: above not worked.my code is:Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
   CreationHelper helper = wb.getCreationHelper();
   Sheet sheet2 = wb.createSheet("image sheet");
   Drawing drawing2 = sheet2.createDrawingPatriarch();
   ClientAnchor anchor2 = helper.createClientAnchor();
   anchor2.setCol1(1);
    anchor2.setRow1(1);
    anchor2.setAnchorType(ClientAnchor.MOVE_AND_RESIZE);
    anchor2.setCol2(20);
    anchor2.setRow2(20);  
    Picture pict2 = drawing2.createPicture(anchor2, pictureIdx);
    pict2.resize();